# Get UI-Grid column data in protractor by binding

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, angular-ui-grid

We recently switched from NG-Grid to UI-Grid, in protractor we used to be able to get an entire columns data using

```
element.all(by.binding('row.entity.name'))
```

this no longer works with UI-Grid, our data service hasn't changed so how would I go about getting the data from the name field in protractor now that we are using UI-Grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the underlying row data using the following code:

```
angular.element('some xpath query or other means').scope().row
```

This should give you back the whole object bound to the row.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.